# Velocity attained by a Loop with an induced current

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

A rectangular loop of resistance R is kept at a certain distance from an infinite straight current carrying conductor. The current is suddenly switched off. The problem was to find the velocity attained by the loop.

When the current is switched off, there will be a rapid change in magnetic flux through the loop which generates a current through the loop. I get the point that the charges in the loop experience a force due to the generated electric field. But what forces are responsible for the loop itself to move?